# JSTL padding int with leading zeros

Tags: jstl, number-formatting

I'm trying to use JSTL to build a form.  I have a select input for the months but I need the months to always be two digits i.e. padded left with a Zero for 1-9.

I have this but obvious it doesn't give me what I want.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
    <select class="formInput">
        <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="12" step="1" varStatus ="status">
            <option><fmt:formatNumber pattern="##" value="${i}" /></option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
```

This has to have been done before but I can't find an example after a bit of searching.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

found the answer: minIntegerDigits

```
<select class="formInput">
    <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="12" step="1" varStatus ="status">
        <option><fmt:formatNumber minIntegerDigits="2" value="${i}" /></option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: `<fmt:formatNumber pattern="00" value="${i}" />` would work as well